# how to install python packages through ssh in ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: python-3.x, virtual-machine

I am trying to use a VM in google cloud to run python code. First I have to install the necessary packages. But I encounter the following error while I want to install "copy" and "timeit":

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement copy (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for copy

Moreover, I have chosen ubuntu 20.04 to work with as a VM. I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: `copy` and `timeit` are built-in packages, they come with the Python interpreter.

Comment: It means that I do not need to install them to run my code?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: and how to add .csv files to the vm? for example MNIST dataset.

Comment: No idea, you should post this as a new question including any relevant information.